Temporal SKD does not return all workflow executions
I have an error in logs which tells that I have error in workflow with 'execute-flow-97bc4090-4cb4-4652-9841-7f01b8fda6f8' id:
Completing activity as failed ({'activity_id': '1', 'activity_type': 'send_email', 'attempt': 23928, 'namespace': 'default', 'task_queue': 'execute-flow-task-queue', 'workflow_id': 'execute-flow-97bc4090-4cb4-4652-9841-7f01b8fda6f8', 'workflow_run_id': 'c2baa95b-8660-42e5-a451-221a05cf54c0', 'workflow_type': 'ExecuteFlowWorkflow'})

So I want to execute a debug script in python to find a similar problem in other workflows. But temporal_client.list_workflows() does not return all workflows that currently running.
To proof it I wrote a simple python code which retrieves a workflow with problem by it's id, then the code tries to find it by temporal_client.list_workflows() but the workflow wasn't found and the number of workflows returned by temporal_client.list_workflows() does not exceeds the limit of page.
async def main():
    temporal_settings = TemporalSettings()
    temporal_client = await create_temporal_client(temporal_settings)

    workflow_handle = temporal_client.get_workflow_handle("execute-flow-97bc4090-4cb4-4652-9841-7f01b8fda6f8")
    print("Workflow id:", workflow_handle.id)

    workflow_executions_count = 0
    async for workflow_execution in temporal_client.list_workflows(page_size=1000):
        workflow_executions_count += 1

        if workflow_execution.id != workflow_handle.id:
            continue

        print("Workflow execution found")
        break

    else:
        print("Workflow execution not found")

    print("Workflow executions count:", workflow_executions_count)

asyncio.run(main())

Output:
Workflow id: execute-flow-97bc4090-4cb4-4652-9841-7f01b8fda6f8
Workflow execution not found
Workflow executions count:  145


I suppose you are using a self-hosted Temporal server, right? Which version of the server? Which persistence engine for your visibility database?

I can think of two possible explanations for what you describe:

It's possible there is simply no Workflow with the given workflow_id. get_workflow_handle don't go to the server, and therefore, won't fail if you give a Workflow ID that doesn't exist. It may have existed at some point in the past, but could have exceeded the namespace's retention policy… Try calling workflow_handle.describe() to confirm that the server indeed knows about that Workflow ID.

The ListWorkflowExecution API is answered from the visibility store. The visibility store is eventual consistent, and some update lag is expected, generally in the order of a few milliseconds. However, due to misconfiguration, underprovisioning or operational issues, it is possible for your visibility store to lag behind considerably, or even to get completely out of sync. If you start a new Workflow Execution, can you see it in list_workflows()?


